# Updating rails from 4.2.8 to 5.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I try update rails from v. 4.2.8 to 5.0.2, but in terminal I have still problems:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
In Gemfile:
rails (= 5.0.2)

datagrid (= 1.5.3) was resolved to 1.5.3, which depends on
  rails (>= 4.0)

mails_viewer was resolved to 0.1.2, which depends on
  rails (>= 3.1.0)

quiet_assets was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
  rails (~> 3.1)

simple_captcha2 (= 0.4.3) was resolved to 0.4.3, which depends on
  rails (>= 4.1)
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
In Gemfile:
coffee-rails (= 4.2.1) was resolved to 4.2.1, which depends on
  railties (< 5.2.x, >= 4.0.0)

doorkeeper (= 4.2.5) was resolved to 4.2.5, which depends on
  railties (>= 4.2)

dotenv-rails was resolved to 2.2.1, which depends on
  railties (< 5.2, >= 3.2)

factory_girl_rails was resolved to 4.8.0, which depends on
  railties (>= 3.0.0)

jquery-rails (= 4.3.1) was resolved to 4.3.1, which depends on
  railties (>= 4.2.0)

momentjs-rails (= 2.17.1) was resolved to 2.17.1, which depends on
  railties (>= 3.1)

momentjs-rails (= 2.17.1) was resolved to 2.17.1, which depends on
  railties (>= 3.1)

quiet_assets was resolved to 1.0.1, which depends on
  railties (~> 3.1)

rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  railties (= 5.0.2)

rails-i18n (= 5.0.4) was resolved to 5.0.4, which depends on
  railties (~> 5.0)

rspec-rails was resolved to 3.6.0, which depends on
  railties (>= 3.0)

rspec-rails was resolved to 3.6.0, which depends on
  railties (>= 3.0)

sass-rails (= 5.0.6) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
  railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)
```

My Gemfile seems like that:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'aasm', '4.12.0'
gem 'active_hash', '1.5.1'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '4.0.0'
gem 'amqp', '1.7.0'
gem 'angularjs-rails', '1.6.2'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails', '0.3.3.8'
gem 'bourbon', '4.3.4'
gem 'bunny', '2.6.5'
gem 'browser', '2.3.0'
gem 'cancancan', '1.16.0'
gem 'carrierwave', '1.1.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'country_select', '3.0.0'
gem 'daemons-rails', '1.2.1'
gem 'datagrid', '1.5.3'
gem 'doorkeeper', '4.2.5'
#gem 'easy_table', '~> 0.0.7'
gem 'eco', '1.0.0'
gem 'em-websocket', '0.5.1'
gem 'enumerize', '2.1.1'
gem 'eventmachine', '1.2.3'
gem 'figaro', '1.1.1'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '4.7.0'
gem 'globalize', github: 'globalize/globalize', branch: 'master', require: 'activemodel-serializers-xml'
gem 'gon', '6.1.0'
gem 'grape', '0.19.2'
gem 'grape-entity', '0.6.1'
gem 'grape-swagger', '0.27.1'
#gem 'has_public_id'
gem 'hashie', '3.5.5'
gem 'http_accept_language', '2.1.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '2.6.3'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'
gem 'json', '2.1.0'
gem 'kaminari', '1.0.1'
gem 'liability-proof', '0.0.9'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '2.17.1'
gem 'mysql2', '0.4.6'
gem 'omniauth', '1.6.1'
gem 'omniauth-identity', '1.1.1'
gem 'omniauth-trezor', '0.1.0'
gem 'omniauth-weibo-oauth2', '0.4.2'
gem 'paper_trail', '7.0.2'
gem 'paranoid2', '1.1.5'
gem 'phonelib', '0.6.11'
gem 'pusher', '1.3.1'
gem 'rack-attack', '5.0.1'
gem 'rails', '5.0.2'
gem 'rails-i18n', '5.0.4'
#gem 'rails-observers'
gem 'rbtree', '0.4.2'
gem 'redis-rails', '5.0.2'
gem 'rest-client', '2.0.2'
gem 'rotp', '3.3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.6'
gem 'simple_captcha2', '0.4.3', require: 'simple_captcha'
gem 'simple_form', '3.4.0'
gem 'slim-rails', '3.1.2'
gem 'twilio-ruby', '4.13.0'
gem 'uglifier', '3.2.0'
gem 'unread', github: 'peatio/unread'
gem 'whenever', '0.9.7'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'brakeman' #security tests
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker', '~> 1.7.3'
  gem 'mails_viewer'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'mina'
  gem 'mina-slack', github: 'peatio/mina-slack', branch: 'master'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'timecop'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'mocha', :require => false
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  # rspec-rails rely on test-unit if rails version less then 4.1.0
  # but test-unit has been removed from ruby core since 2.2.0
  gem 'test-unit'
end
```

Does have somebody Idea how to fix this problems? I try different versions, but still issues. Maybe it need be changed some version, I am not sure.
I need use the 5+ version of Rails. Still I do many changing, but I am facing issues. Bundler version 1.14.6 I try delete all files gems with gem uninstall -aIx and install from beginning and bundle also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to remove `quiet_assets` from your application, because even the latest version ([`1.1.0`](https://rubygems.org/gems/quiet_assets/versions/1.1.0) at the moment), does not support Rails 5.0. Furthermore on [README on GitHub](https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets) tells us that the gem is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks spickerman..just wasted 30 minutes trying to figure out what was wrong! You saved the day.